# Installing Certbot to use HTTPS in JBoss EAP 7

Tags: lets-encrypt

Well, My problem starts with **Google Maps API**. Working local everything is fine, but When i published my system in web (Digital Ocean Host) i discovered that Google Maps API only works with **HTTPS protocol**.

So, searching in the internet i found the https://letsencrypt.org/ , a good way to use HTTPS without pay, beacause i'm justing testing, not production yet.

But i'm using a JBOSS EAP 7 and i didn't found any tutorial in letsencrypt.org to JBOSS, so i found this link: https://knowles.co.za/creating-renewing-a-lets-encrypt-certificate-for-apache-and-wildfly/.

Following the WildFly tutorial i tried execute this step:

```
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOURDOMAIN/fullchain.pem -inkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOURDOMAIN/privkey.pem -out YOURKEYSTORENAME.p12 -name KEYSTOREALIAS
```

PS: I changed the YOURDOMAIN to my domain.

I got the following error:

```
No such file or directory fullchain.pem
```

This file didn't should be created automatically ?

Comment: "a good way to use HTTPS without pay, beacause i'm justing testing, not production yet.", first, do not worry, lets encrypt works great in production, we use it already.

On the other hand i would recommend to extract that layer and use something like nginx as a SSL terminator, using nginx with letsencrypt, creating a proxy with will handle the https traffic and will redirect to your server as normal HTTP, this will let your app ready to be behind a load balancer or acting as a single node with one

Comment: Thanks this is the better solutions.